# Synchronous Up/Down counter which shows given sequence simultaneously on 5 x 7-segment displays

Tags: digital-logic, counter, synchronous

I was given a project to design a Synchronous Up/Down counter which displays my sequence (2,1,0,6,5) on 5 x 7-segment displays simultaneously. I started first by designing the Up/Down counter and simulating it. I used both Multisim and Crocodile Clips to simulate my design and it works fine.

The problem comes when I need to display the entire sequence on the 7-segment displays. I used a 5-bit ring counter using D flip-flops with a BJT transistor and 10k Ohm resistors to do this but the sequence doesn't display correctly on either of the two programs. On Crocodile Clips only the '1' in the sequence displays and Multisim shows all the numbers but very incorrectly.

I'm not sure what to do to fix this problem. If anyone can help I'd be very grateful. The main problem I'm facing is that I cannot get the sequence to display. The full sequence doesn't show on all the 7-segment displays simultaneously like I need it to, instead it still shows the sequence as it counts from 2,1,0,6,5 up and down. In Multisim I cannot get the numbers to display correctly and in Crocodile Clips there is only one number that displays.

Here's all my work so far:

Counter Equation: [image]

Multisim Design: [image]

Crocodile Clips Design: [image]

Link to Crocodile Clips file: [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xQMcktAwzIk6JKVFlqMo38wl2BEaw-bW)

Link to Multisim file : [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k75Lr6KgBYZID1tRewMweom-1iisoTy4)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question (not in comments) and expand upon "can't seem to get it to work" otherwise we won't know what we're investigating. At first glance, I think it's the bounce from your push switch but there may be other problems. I imagine your simulation didn't simulate switch bounce properly.

Comment: How do you expect your ring counter to get initialised?

Comment: I've updated the problem so it can be more clear now about what I'm having trouble with

Comment: I've tried connecting the clock pulse to the ring counter to initialize it but that does nothing. I'm not sure if that's right or not.

Comment: You need a decent reset circuit. Then you could connect it to the /PRE and /CLR (or equiv.) inputs on your ring counter DFFs to initialise things. You can make a simple one with an R-C circuit (10K and 100 nF would do). In reality, you'd have a reverse-biased diode in parallel with R. By the way, tie unused gate inputs to inactive (low or high as each input requires).

Comment: Thanks for that TonyM, I'll do all that now and see if it helps

Comment: @Jason I don't understand why there are so many 7-seg displays. Your sequence would appear to require only one 7-seg display (to me, anyway.) What's up? Also, are you focused on using the FFs to directly tie to the segments as well as count that sequence? If so, isn't it (6) FFs required (for the "0"?)

Comment: Ok so an update, I added the reset circuit which to my understanding is a power on reset circuit so I built it exactly that way with the 10k Ohm resistor connected to VCC and a 100uF capacitor which is grounded. I then took the node between the resistor and cap and connected those to the first DFF's /PRE and the /CLRs of the rest of the DFFs and it doesn't change anything. I also a reverse biased diode in parallel with each of the 10k Ohm resistors which are connected to the transistors and nothing changed. I don't think I made any mistake so is there something else that could be wrong?

Comment: @jonk The reason I have all the 7-segment displays is because I'm required to display the entire sequence at once on each 7-segment. So it should be one 
7-segment per digit. Also I'm not sure I understand what you mean by your second question, maybe you could rephrase it?

Comment: @Jason So you are running a fast enough clock that the eye won't see the multiplexing? If fast, the up/down direction won't be noticed, right? (You'd need to clock it slow to see.)

Comment: @jonk Yes I plan on using 100Hz in the final circuit, but before that I first need to fix the current problem I'm facing which is the numbers don't display properly ( some segments don't light up and others light up when they're not supposed to) and I'm not sure if it's the ring counter or the transistors causing the issue